# How to report a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just saw a tag named [malicous](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malicous) it is definitely misspelled and even if the spelling is corrected it doesn't look like a good tag to me. I was wondering if there is a report tag mechanism or may be some sort of tag cleanup.

Obviously no individual can take a decision about such tags but there should be a way to bring this in front of the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flagging for a mod is probably the simplest way to get a misspelt tag sorted.

As for tags which are just wrong, raising them here so we can discuss them is definitely the best route. I'll get some time to look at the questions with that tag to see if it should stay.

Update: Actually, as that one has zero questions, it should get removed automatically by a cleanup script at some point.

Comment: It was under new tags..